# web2py: possible to submit multiple forms with a single 'submit' button?

Tags: javascript, python, html, dom, web2py

Is it possible to submit multiple forms with a single 'submit' button? If so, what's the way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is strictly speaking, not a `web2py` question but a HTML (DOM - document object model) and manipulating DOM with `javascript` question.

You can submit 2 (or more forms) in one go, clicking on one single button, by using `javascript`.

Like this:-

```
<form id="id1" ...> ...</form>
<form id="id2" ...> ...</form>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id1').submit();document.getElementById('id2').submit();" />
```

You will probably run into problems when you have to requests POSTed to two separate urls/functions in your web2py application which now needs to be handled concurrently?

The right approach is probably that you will probably need to write a function that changes your form objects into fieldsets as part of one single form.

In django, formsets does exactly this and converts multiple forms into fieldsets belonging to only 1 single HTML form in the template so what was original "multiple forms" become part of 1 single form in the frontend.

Like this:-

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.id }}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ form.title }}</li>
            {% if formset.can_delete %}
                <li>{{ form.DELETE }}</li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

`web2py`:-

http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1458/two-forms-on-one-page-with-custom-forms-to-update-record

```
def new():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(db.contact,db.groups)

    if form.accepts(request.vars):
        _id_user = db.contacts.insert(**db.contacts._filter_fields(form.vars))

        form.vars.contact = _id_user

        id = db.groups.insert(**db.groups._filter_fields(form.vars))

        response.flash = 'User registered successfully'
    return locals()
```

which returns to your web2py template 1 single form only.

Comment: Thanks, Calvin. Sorry if the question was vague. I wanted to put a form in each header of a web2py grid - the alternative seemed to be to edit the code for the grid class itself. I solved the problem by creating a bunch of forms, the first one with a submit button and a bunch of hidden input fields, the others with input fields. When the submit button on the first form is pressed, the values of the others forms' input fields are copied to the first form with jquery. Only the form form is submitted, and the values from all of the other forms are submitted with it.

Comment: Update this on your question (with html code snippets, python code snippets etc) so others may help... and your question won't get closed as "not a real question" :-)